# How do I check if items in a array are present in a string php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array of items, how do I scan a string and detect if the items in the array exist anywhere in the string. I seen other post that are similar to this question but none have worked. Maybe it is because I'm using wordpress

### ex:

```
$string = get_the_title();// "The Man Who Wants You – Amos Lee [Vevo Official Video]" ---the string
$bads = get_the_tags();//  array('Amos Lee', 'Foo Fighters', 'U2'); array of items

foreach($bads as $bad) {
    $place = strpos($string, $bad);
    if (!empty($place)) {
        echo "True";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Not True";
    }
}
```

Comment: Use strict comparison checking `if ($place !== false) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, check if `strpos` doesn't return false:

```
foreach($bads as $bad) {
    if (strpos($string, $bad) !== FALSE) {
        echo "True";
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Not True";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

the return value of [Strpos](http://php.net/strpos) is false if the substring is not there, otherwise it will return the position of the substring therfore you have to check if the value is false or not.